# Can you help me with a listener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have a function of `showDiaglog`.
I just want to, when user tap checkbox the `diaglog` shown, and the spinner also, but I got a problem with listener. Everytime I open settings, the popup show up twice.

First because of listener of spinner then second because one of my setting checked.
I save every changes in that setting.

Can you help me?

```
selectLanguage
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        saveSettingan(Key_Select, position);

                        if (position == 0) {
                            setDefaultLocal();
                        } else {
                            setLocal("in");
                        }
                        showDialog();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

and this one

```
case R.id.checkAcak:
            saveSettingan(Key_Acak, isChecked);
            showDialog();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a boolean which remembers the visibility of the dialog. Your show dialog should include this:

```
if (isDialogVisible) 
    return;

isDialogVisible = true;
```

Then you set a dismiss listener to set `isDialogVisible` to false.

Comment: I used it but it still show popup. in savesetting, i save it in sharedpreference. About key_acak, or even language, when is loaded in function onCheckedChange() one of value that loaded is show popup at the first open setting. im still dont know the logic to solve this. sory for my bad english